# How to fix 'The project you were looking for could not be found' when using git clone

Tags: git, gitlab, project, git-bash, cloning

I am trying to clone a project from gitlab to my local machine. I have been granted rights as a developer, and use the command 'git clone

- None of the protocols work (ssh and https neither work)

The error message I am getting:

```
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/KZA_Connected/skilltree.git/' not found
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 190):

I solved this by simply adding username to url like below,

before:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab_user/myrepo.git

after:
https://gitlabusername@gitlab.com/gitlab_user/myrepo.git

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. remember 'gitlabusername' is your gitlab user name and second gitlab username would be project owner gitlab so total URL would be  
https://your_gitlab_username@gitlab.com/repo_owner_gitlab_username/repo_name.git

Comment: its 2020 and GitLab hasn't fixed that button on their page to include the username in the url to copy paste to `git clone`?

Comment: second example worked for me.

Answer (score 63):

Today, I was having the same issue. The repo was working fine at my home machine, but when I tried the same repo in other machine I started facing the same error. I was using below URL

```
https://gitlab.com/{gitlab_user}/project_repo.git
```

And now I changed above URL to below

```
https://{gitlab_user}@gitlab.com/gitlab_user/project_repo.git
```

And it worked for me. Above solution was found at below URL

```
https://medium.com/@imstudio/gitlab-the-project-you-were-looking-for-could-not-be-found-issue-685944aa5485
```

Hope this helps other.

Answer (score 55):

I have two gitlab accounts. For both I use ssh keys. Both are hosted by gitlab (not self-hosted).

When you run

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

It will return your username.

```
Welcome to GitLab, @username1!
```

I was using ssh for @username1 and @username2. It defaults to the first ssh found. So, AFAIK, it's impossible to have two accounts with ssh.

My solution was to rm ssh key from the gitlab account I am not using.

Comment: +1 because this might help in the case of a multiple gitlab users conflict, I have read about that elsewhere, and this is likely a good workaround, without having tested it, though.

Comment: You can set up hostname aliases to use the keys with different accounts, see https://gist.github.com/oanhnn/80a89405ab9023894df7

Comment: Further to Eliot's comment covering using aliases on GitHub, a similar thing is possible on GitLab. After assigning aliases in the ssh config (`Host USERNAME.gitlab.com`), you can then eg. clone with `git@USERNAME.gitlab.com:REPO_OWNER/REPO.git` See: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/

Comment: I just added my other gitlab account as a collaborator and it works perfectly fine for me under my circumstances

Comment: that's great answer that helped me to understand the issue.

Comment: Not impossible. See [Use different accounts on a single GitLab instance](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/ssh.html#use-different-accounts-on-a-single-gitlab-instance)

Answer (score 33):

On mac osx, it usually means that your ssh credentials are not loaded. Brute force solution:

```
cd ~/.ssh
ssh-add *
```

I have to do this every time my Macbook reboots.

Comment: Thank you so much! How much do I hate Apple...

Answer (score 32):

Simple Answer: Reset your already existing origin using the following command.

`git remote set-url origin https://gitlabUsername@gitlab.com/some-group/project.git`

For you it's,

```
git remote set-url origin https://gitlabUsername@gitlab.com/KZA_Connected/skilltree.git
```

`git remote -v`  (To check if the changes are reflected), then

`git push origin master`

Finished.

If it's the first time after the `git init`

Then

> `git remote add origin https://gitlabUsername@gitlab.com/gitlabUsername/project_repo.git`

Because `git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/gitlabUsername/project_repo.git` will not work, use the above  instead.

If still you get the error, then Remove remote origin by the following and add a new one again

`git remote remove origin`

Comment: `git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com:USERNAME/PROJECTNAME.git` 

worked to update to SSH push. Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

**I solved the above problem**

**Before:**  `https://gitlab.com/gitlab_user/myrepo.git`

**After:**  `https://<gitlabusername>@gitlab.com/gitlab_user/myrepo.git`

**Explanation:**

Type your **gitlabUsername** in place of `<gitlabusername>`.

Now, it will ask for gitlab password for that your account.
Enter the correct password and the project will be cloned successfully.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks you

Answer (score 17):

There is credential manager on windows, which contains details about credentials of your host here is s.s of credential manager
[image]

1. First of all make sure you have same user credentials which have access to repository which you are trying to clone.
   If you have correct credentials

then try this url formatter

```
https://{username}@gitlab.com/username/repo-name.git
```

in your case it will be like this

```
'https://username@gitlab.com/KZA_Connected/skilltree.git/'
```

i was able to solve my problem deleting my credentials and adding them again
i hope this help others too

-- Important note
this credential manager save your global credentials, you can set your local credentials too using git config

```
git config --local user.name "Your name"
```

```
git config --local user.email "Your email"
```

```
git config --local credential.helper "store"
```

if you set `credential.helper` to store, in current local git scope it will ask you password every time you do action like pull, push etc

if you want to reset credential.helper, then simply set it back to `manager`
it will work fine as before

Answer (score 16):

If you (like me) have added multiple ssh keys, the solution is to explicitly state which key should be used for a remote host.

Add the following lines to the ~/.ssh/config file, depending on your use case:

```
Host bitbucket.org
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host gitlab.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Comment: I have mulitple ssh keys as well, and this was not enough. For me it was also needed to also run 'ssh-add ~/.ssh/<id_rsa file>', after which the different keys could be found.

Comment: Yes, 'ssh-add' is a given, even for a single ssh key. It tells the authentication agent about your keys.

Answer (score 12):

If adding the ssh key does not work, follow this -

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

Then add the ssh key

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/<id_rsa>
```

Comment: great its works for me , sits ave my time

Answer (score 12):

First of all verify your credentials are correct.

```
git config user.email
git config user.name
```

If they are correct, try appending your `username@` before your repo address.

E.g. Instead of

```
git clone https://repo.abc.com/projectname.git
```

Try

```
git clone https://username@repo.abc.com/projectname.git
```

Comment: `git config` are NOT credentials. They're just local labels to mark your local commits.

Comment: It's worked for me, in my case I'm using tithed and Gilab, by default I have configured GitHub in my Xcode. So manually I cloned using your suggested method. `git clone https://username@gitlab.com/B********n/my_project_name.git`

Answer (score 9):

If you are facing the issue for a fresh repo

Just simply change the gitlab default https url from https://gitlab.com/rscodelab/project.git to https://rscodelab@gitlab.com/rscodelab/project.git

> for example

> `git clone https://gitlab.com/gitlabusername/project.git`

> to

> `git clone https://gitlabusername@gitlab.com/gitlabusername/project.git`

Answer (score 6):

Put username before the url like this:

```
git clone https://username@repo.abc.com/projectname.git
```

To add git to an existing folder accordingly:

```
git remote add origin https://username@repo.abc.com/projectname.git
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution: it was due my windows credentials being set to an other email account.

Comment: incase anyone don't know how to change credentials check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63899445/3946527

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was not adding .git at the end of URL.

```
https://gitlab.com/{gitlab_user}/project_repo
```

corrected to

```
https://gitlab.com/{gitlab_user}/project_repo.git
```

This might seem like a silly mistake, but that was it!

Comment: Thanks. That was the problem in my case. The push worked fine from a GUI which, presumably, added the `.git` suffix automatically. It did not work from the command line until I've set the url to the `.git` version though.

Answer (score 2):

If it's the first time after the git init command, Then use the below command

**git remote add origin https://gitlabUsername@gitlab.com/gitlabUsername/project_repo.git**

Because git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/gitlabUsername/project_repo.git will not work, use the above instead.

If still you get the error, then Remove remote origin by the following and retry again by adding the origin using the correct command.
to remove origin - git remote remove origin

Comment: "https://gitlabUsername@gitlab.com/gitlabUsername/project_repo.git" didn't work. The only thing that worked for me is "https://gitlabUsername@gitlab.com/group/subgroup/project.git"

Comment: Alternatively, with ssh: "git@gitlab.com:group/subgroup/project.git". It's very annoying, because I couldn't find an example anywhere with groups and subgroups, all the examples have username instead of group and that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I was frustrated about this error

Following Steps solved the error(Run All this in terminal)

1. `ssh -T git@gitlab.com`
   Output -> Welcome to GitLab, @username!

- Go to "Git Bash" just like cmd. Right click and "Run as Administrator".
  Type ssh-keygen
- Press enter.
- It will ask you to save the key to the specific directory.
  Press enter. It will prompt you to type password or enter without password.
- The public key will be created to the specific directory.
- Now go to the directory and open .ssh folder.
- You'll see a file id_rsa.pub. Open it on notepad. Copy all text from it.
- Go to https://gitlab.com/-/profile/keys or
  Paste here in the "key" textfield.
- Now click on the "Title" below. It will automatically get filled.
  -Then click "Add key".command

2. Now You Clone the project using

   `git clone https://username@gitlab.com/organization_name/project_name.git`

Answer (score 2):

If you are still facing the issue while cloning then try cloning with personal token

```
git clone https://<username>:<token>@gitlab.example.com/tanuki/awesome_project.git
```

For more refer this [link.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/start-using-git.html#clone-using-a-token)

Answer (score 1):

On Intellij go to

Git->Manage Remotes

then select the url and edit your url
to be https://{gitlab_user}@gitlab.com/gitlab_user/project_repo.git

Click Ok. On your password request. You can use your gitlab access token as password if you face authentication challenges.

Answer (score 0):

if your git --version > 2.10

run the following command in your project repo :

```
git config --add core.sshCommand "ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i ~/.ssh/path-to-your-key -F /dev/null"
```

[from this page](https://codeconcisely.com/posts/switching-ssh-keys-between-git-projects/)

Answer (score 0):

I got new account from my company gitlab so I added new ssh key but I got permission issue when tried to clone via ssh.

Then I tried `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` which returned `Welcome to GitLab, @<my_old_account>!`
I realized I have to remove old ssh keys from `.ssh` folder. I removed them and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solutions but none work for me. But they helped me in understanding the problem. I had two Gitlab accounts on my new PC.

1 - Remove the Gitlab account in credential Manager Windows.

2 - No need to change the Url of the project.

3 - If you try to push now it will show another error and shows you a pop-up to sign into GitLab.

4 - If you were to sign up using a username/password. The problem will still persist. It will not work. The solution is to sign in through a Web Browser like chrome/edge. It will work. You will be able to push the project.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by changing my role on gitlab, before my role was a developer and asked to owner change it to maintiner and this problem solved for me

Answer (score -2):

- Open a spotlight search.
- Go to Keychain Access.
- Search for GitLab.
- Make sure your account(username) and password match the GitLab credentials for the account you're using to clone the repo.

Comment: This answer helped me. I had multiple accounts configured with incorrect password in one of the account. I had update the correct password. You are a SAVIOUR.