# How to fix the git error: Repository not found

Tags: git, gitlab

I create a new project and trying to push on the new repository.

What I did is like this:

```sh
git init
git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/test.dev/project1.git
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
git push origin master
```

and here's the error:

```
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/test.dev/project1.git/' not found
```

I already try to remove and reapply still doesn't work.

Comment: Please confirm again that such a repo exists at that URL.

Comment: @iBug when I try to public it works but when I change to private the error appears

Comment: have you try to push via ssh rather than https (and set up ssh key beforehand)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If None of the protocols (ssh and https) works and such a repo exists, then*

Find the answer on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571213/how-to-fix-the-project-you-were-looking-for-could-not-be-found-when-using-git/57558422).

Solve this by simply adding username to url like below,

**Before:** `https://gitlab.com/gitlab_user/myrepo.git`

**After:** `https://gitlabusername@gitlab.com/gitlab_user/myrepo.git`

Remember **'gitlabusername'** is *your gitlab user name* and second **gitlab_user** would be *project owner* so the complete URL would be : `https://your_gitlab_username@gitlab.com/repo_owner_gitlab_username/repo_name.git`

Answer (score 0):

in case your repository is private, you need to use ssh
that would look like `git@gitlab.com:test.dev/project1.git`
replacing your remote origin would help you
the command to do that would look like this:
`git remote set-url origin git@gitlab.com:test.dev/project1.git`

Comment: `in case your repository is private, you need to use ssh` => I use private repos on gitlab.com over https without any problem. If there is a specific case linked to OP's question which forces him to use ssh, you should explain that in your answer. As far as I'm concerned, with the current available info, the repository just does not exist at all.