# Android studio and GitLab - how integration?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, github, gitlab

I need use GitLab repository in my Flutter project(Android Studio).
First, I tried "New->Get from version control", but I have error:

```
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't 
have permission to view it
```

I started looking for a solution on the net and only found this [manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677931/connecting-to-gitlab-repositories-on-android-studio). The key step is to add the remote repository. I tried it, but have error:

[image]

maybe I need to add login/password for gitlab to Android Studio? I will try to do this, but in the settings it is not available (only git)

[image]

any advice? I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571213/how-to-fix-the-project-you-were-looking-for-could-not-be-found-when-using-git) - need change url for clone(add userName):

```
before: https://gitlab.com/gitlab_user/myrepo.git

after: https://gitlabusername@gitlab.com/gitlab_user/myrepo.git
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem
[image]

and then import it

[image]

If you already checked it out and you want to add a new remote, I recommend to use CLI

```
git remote add upstream https://git.something.info/privat/sensoric.git
```

Btw, in general, I recommend to use CLI to understand what you do **exactly**

Comment: I tried it, but I have error :  remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it

Comment: I updated my question

Comment: Ok, you have a permission/connection issue. Without url and user+pw I can only guess what's wrong