# Git doesn't work in IDEA: "The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it."

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I faced the problem exclusively in IntelliJ IDEA (if it's important, version is: 2021.3.3 (Ultimate Edition)). OS is Windows 10.
When I trying to update, to push, to clone project inside IDEA I get an error:

```
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z8wV.png)

it has become reproducible with all my work repositories today. Yesterday everything were good.

As example, when I tryed to clone project by command **git clone** in PowerShell - it works fine, repo was cloned. So the problem is only for git in IDEA. Also, I can open and download my repos in UI git interface.

Hope, the community has already faced that problem.

**Expecting behaviour:**

Commits pushed | project updated

**Fact behaviour:**

I get an error.

I have already tried:

1. Reinstall Git
2. Recreate settings.xml
3. Tried git commands with login in IDEA's terminal and it's still doesnt work(this is solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571213/how-to-fix-the-project-you-were-looking-for-could-not-be-found-when-using-git)

```
https://{gitlab_user}@gitlab.com/gitlab_user/project_repo.git
```

4. Tried **File -> Invalidate Caches..**
5. Tried **File -> Repair IDE..**
6. Tried clear the password in **Settings -> Appearence and Behavior -> Password**
7. **Test** button in **Settings -> Version Control -> Git** returns git version.
8. Tried to clear git's credentials in **Windows Account Manager**

Probably I should add my login to git commands like N3 somewhere in IDEA, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Problem have solved. The reason is wrong credentials for gitlab in **_netrc**  file.